# update progress bar with Firebase uploading

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I tried to add a progress bar to uploading files on firebase. but unfortunalty it does not indicate upload progress. both logcat & progress bar  only indicate when file reached to 100%

```
   uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = 100.0 * (taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                System.out.println("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
            int currentprogress = (int) progress;
                progressBar.setProgress(currentprogress);
            }
        }).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                System.out.println("Upload is paused");
            }
        });
```

Comment: The progress bar fires for 256KB increments. So if your file is smaller than 256KB, it will jump from 0% to 100% in one update.

Comment: I tried  files like 2MB , 4MB  log cat updates "upload is 0% done" for like 5 or 6 times . but number is not incriminating nor progress bar updating

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is there any way to fire up listener below 256 KB???

Comment: is there any solution that can track increaments of uploading file with is less than 256kb?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Change the grouping of terms in your calculation of `progress` to force conversion to float.  As your code is now, you are dividing two longs.  The result of the division will be 0 until `getBytesTransferred() == getTotalByteCount()`, then it will be 1.

```
 double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
```

Comment: Ouch... that's a silly mistake in the code sample. I've made a note to fix it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sir I have already reported the issue at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215428

Comment: is the style of progress bar horizontal ?

Comment: @nivla360 Post your code and error output as a new question

Comment: I have did the same but still not getting updates. not even console. have any idea what can be wrong..., same code as above

Answer (score -1):

When you are sending data up to storage you can observe the progress of what you are uploading.

```
let uploadTask = profileRef.putData(data, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
     if let error = error {
              // Awesome error handling 
     }
}
```

Now that you have started sending data up observe the changes. The snapshot you get back has a property on it called **fractionCompleted**. You can set a progress bar with min and max value of 0 and 1 and set the value to the fraction completed value. Or if you prefer just show the percentage of the upload as it comes back.

```
task.observe(.progress, handler: { (snap) in
   print("Our upload progress is: \(String(describing: snap.progress?.fractionCompleted))")
})
```