# Firebase Storage: Showing Progress of File Upload

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Just wanted to improve the File Upload of Firebase Storage with a progress dialog.

```
.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            progressDialog.setMessage((int) progress + "");
        }
    });
```

But the getBytesTransferred() and getTotalByteCount methods of TaskSnapshot does not allow to be called here. Android Studio says: This method should be only accessed from a test or within private scope.
The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask.TaskSnapshot.html#getBytesTransferred()) does not say that there are any problems and it seemed that this is the regular way to show the progress (
[update progress bar with Firebase uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278249/update-progress-bar-with-firebase-uploading) )

So why the methods don't want to be called?

Edit: Works with `@SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")`

Comment: I think it is a warning. Please try adding `@SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")`.

Comment: Yep, this works! Thanks ^^

Comment: What version of the Storage SDK are you using?

Comment: You could write it as your own answer instead of placing the answer in the question itself. :) It helps for who go down for answers.